# How to install QGIS 2.2 instead of 2.4 to get a working OpenLayers plugin again?

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I use ubuntu . I don't know how to return installed qgis 2.2 
I try uninstall qgis 2.4 and try find how to install old version qgis 2.2
Please .. tell me how to install old version qgis 2.2 for ubunut 12.4

Answer (score 1):

The ubuntugis stable ppa still has a working version of QGIS 2.2 for precise:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ppa

You might have to uninstall the current version, and remove qgis.org and/or ubuntgis unstable from the source list to avoid conflicts.